# Where can I offer a graphic task and only pay the best from several solutions?

Tags: designers, freelance, hiring

I have a task for graphic design, which I want to outsource online.

Ideally I would like to post my task, have several designers post their solutions, and then award the best one of them.

Where can I do this?

Comment: Online "contests" like these are generally a terrible thing for graphic designers, the graphic design industry and pretty much everyone involved. There are plenty of places you can do it, but you probably won't get much advice on it here (it's akin to asking the designers here "how can I avoid paying you.. or pay you pennies if I like what you do?").

Comment: Seems kinda mean to have maybe five people working for you, only paying one. Like eating several dishes at a restaurant, but only paying for the ones you like. Does life has to be that cruel?

Comment: Besides the points made above, this question is a bit broad for our Q&A format and is likely to be closed as such

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend upwork.com. you can view many designers portfolios and work history, propose your job and then they bid on it.

In their bid they describe their plans or "solution" but they don't all submit work.

There is a lot of talent on there and its totally safe and convenient for clients like yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend 99designs.com. Where you can launch a contest and also view designers portfolio and work history.